# For which a ∈ R is the map F(a) : R^2 to R^2 surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ be a map defined by $f (x, y) = (ax + y, (a + 6)x + ay)$.

From definition, $f$ is said to be surjective if for every $y\in Y$ exists at least one $x \in X : f(x)=y$
Therefore, i made 2 linear equations of 5 unknowns:

$ax + y = u$

$(a + 6)x + ay = v$

I've rewritten this into a matrix notation and tried to define $x$, but I am stuck.

Could anyone help me navigate through this?

Comment: Is the rank of a certain matrix maximum?

Comment: In the aim of being clearer: @Deif's comment is a leading question/hint.

Comment: Not sure that I understand?

Comment: you say that you rewrote the equation in matrix notation. Please do so for us, so we can be sure that we know what you are talking about.  I'm afraid you're going to need math formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: with respect to the standard bases, the matrix of $f$ is
$$ \left(\begin{array}{cc}a & 1 \\ a+6 & a \end{array}\right) $$
$f$ is surjective ( bijective due to finite dimension) if the above matrix is invertible. When does this happen?

---

With more rudimentary tools: we must be able to solve
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}a & 1 & u \\ a+6 & a & v \end{array}\right)$$
for the standard basis of $\mathbb R^2$. So $(u,v)=(1,0)$ and $(u,v)=(0,1)$ (or any basis you want, it makes no difference).

Comment: I did exactly that. With the exact same coordinates of the basis. I suppose that the answer for the first question would be to use a determinant. Ergo, for a map to be surjective, its determinant must be non-zero. The determinant would after the calculation then become a quadratic equation, it would yield 2 answers for which the basis is not surjective (bijective in this sense). Only thing I see wrong here is that we didn't yet cover this topic. Is there any alternative to do this using high-school obtained knowledge?

Comment: The problem is about whether solutions exist to a parametrised linear system. So it's not about solving the system, it's about its solvability. There is the Kronecker-Capelli theorem for that, but involves notions such as "rank of a matrix", which is most comfortable to check using determinants. I have no clue what they teach in high school these days. @micfold

Comment: Okay, many thanks for your answers! Take care.